# How to share only one tab in the new Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with two tabs:

*First* one is a public one where I want to invite specific customers to edit it.

*Second* one is just for my team and I would like it to be invisible to the customers.

In new (May 2014) Google Sheets I am not able to do it.

In a few words: On a Google Sheets with two tabs how to let some users edit only first tab and not show them the second, while keeping the full spreadsheet editable for another group of users?

Comment: in the previous version of google docs this was possible on the single sheet, now it seems that if the doc is shared in readonly with a user all sheeet are anyway visible.

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I managed to do this with 2 separate spreadsheets.
Using the `IMPORTRANGE` feature I copied the full sheet 1 to the second document, and in the second document I created the second sheet.

Tricky but working